# Woocommerce product search result layout page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I have made a 'archive-product-custom.php' file who is called in 'taxonomy-product-cat.php'.

I do this to easily change the layout of product when a user is looking on a specific category page (in the archive-product-custom i changed the wc_get_template_part to my "content-product-custom" file)

This is the only one and easiest method i found for doing what i want without broke the entire theme (content-product template is used everywhere.. related, cart, up-sells, cross-sells)

Is it possible to change the layout of the search result with the same above techniques?

Or maybe you have a better solution for me? All i want is a custom product layout on each category page and search result without changing the cross-sells,  up-sells and related product layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually there is a comment at the start of each WC template file, which basically says: `This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/wc-template-name.php.`. This is the correct and recommended way to override WooCommerce templates.

I think you should look into having a child theme for when there is a theme that already have those templates overridden, or even if it doesn't.
See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ for reference.

What I said above is applicable for the `search.php` as well. Of course it will depend very much on your theme setup.

If you provide more details on where and what you're trying to achieve, then I can be more specific.

Comment: I've already made a child of the paid theme, i've tweaked different things for now like the style of the products list when you are in a specific category (instead of little box i made wider rectangle)  but for the search result page its different. The paid theme doesnt have a search.php file, it contains searform.php where you can customize the search form but not the result page. (note that even if the theme doesnt have a search.php file it still been designed like other product category page)
My apologize for my english i've some difficulties to explain my problems clearly

Comment: @JiyoV If the parent theme is missing an `search.php` then it most likely uses the `index.php` file. You can override it within your child theme ( just copy the parent's index file there ). If you would like tweak something within in only for the search results do a conditional check `is_search()`. The other thing is to create a search.php of your own. :)

Take a look at this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#search-result

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly i've done this in my archive-product.php

```php
if (is_search())
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-custom' );
else
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
```

I don't know if its the right way but it works.
Thanks for your help @Kuliraj